# Why didn't Blake and Gordon tell about the "timed" nature of the bomb to Captain Jones themselves?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

My question is to seek an explanation about the scene with special forces. I couldn't think of any possible plot advancement or plot changes that the scene depicted.

Let's take a quick recap. Fox and Miranda were held captive and they both knew the bomb was timed. Blake took Jones to meet Fox secretly in order to brief him about the "updated info" on the bomb. When Fox was just about to brief Jones regarding the timed nature of the bomb, Blake said, "here comes the important part" (which clearly shows that Blake knows that the bomb is timed and it will go off regardless of anything). Jones hearing the brief said to Blake that we'll handle it from here leading to the fighting scene with Bane and died.

So Blake, knowing all, could tell Jones even before coming to the meeting that bomb was timed. Why didn't he? Even Blake said to Miranda that someone sold us out but she was seen later with Gordon confronting Foley so they even didn't doubt her due to this episode. So why put this scene with no purpose served to the plot?

I already had a discussion with *Flater* on his answer about what could've been done by the army to save the city (plot changes), using the information provided in the film (not in-universe, I think). I do seek the **fit in the plot** about this scene.

There are many scenes in a movie but they all contribute to the plot. An example is from Dark Knight where Joker burnt all the cash to second Alfred's point that "some people just wanna watch the world burn" and as he himself said, "...it is to send a message". So it gives insight about the Joker (that he can't be bought) and further contributed to the plot of the movie.

So, why Blake took Jones to meet Fox only to know the bomb is timed while Blake already knows it? There must be a reason for this scene or a significance, not just *tangentiality*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP tries to rewrite the plot when faced with in-universe justifications. This makes the question unanswerable without having to provide feedback to alternate plot possibilties that the OP presents as "counterevidence".

Comment: @Flater Sorry, I disagree. I intend to know the **reason** (a plausible one) why Blake took Jones to meet Fox? Comments to your answer were in hope of further understanding/discussing your answer (logic), to which I still don't find myself agreeable.

Answer (score 2):

> Jones wouldn't have died if they both told him earlier in the secret meet up and the army outside the city would've devised another strategy, perhaps not blocking the bridges/tunnels and letting people out.

This is highly unlikely. The bridges and tunnels were being barricaded by the army because they had been explicitly told that the bomb would be set off if anyone escaped over the bridge.

Even with the bomb on a timer, that doesn't quite change the scenario. If **anyone** crosses that bridge, the bomb will be set off (regardless of whether there was a timer or not).

You also have to consider it from the army's point of view, or more specifically, the soldiers on site. If they allow people to cross the bridge, they condemn the other citizens of Gotham to die in the explosion. No person wants to make that call and have the blood on their hands.

> Why Blake took Jones to meet Fox only to know the bomb is timed while Blake already knows it?

Just because we see a short meeting, does not mean that there was no other discussion taking place during that meeting.

Not everything is shown in a movie, because they need to fit an entire plot in the movie. The meeting scene could have been shortened in editing, thus omitting further details that Fox gave Jones about the bomb (expected blast radius, possible fallout, ...) because that knowledge wasn't needed for the plot to continue (it's tangential at best).

Comment: People can be led off in any another way, it was just a suggestion. My key question was the irrelevancy of Jones and Fox meeting; the whole scene in fact. What purpose did it fulfill?

Comment: Adding to above comment, Fox can also provide an alternative to stop triggering the bomb (the thing he took out from "The Bat", which was later used by Gordon) so even Bane or Talia cannot trigger the bomb hence facilitating the people to escape.

Comment: @Najam: Note that the alternative only stops the **manual** trigger, not the timed detonation. The timed detonation isn't really "intentional", it's the expected time for the reactor to explode because it has been unstable ever since it was taken by Bane. Batman only appears back in Gotham when the timer is already critically low (for obvious plot tension reasons). Fox has always kept a "don't want to know" attitude about Bruce's activities, so it stands to reason that Fox doesn't know **where** the Bat car is stored, and doesn't have access to it until Batman re-emerges.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, but I think this Reactor thing was quite public then and Fox **can share** with Gordon or Blake how to disarm it since it'd have nothing to do with Batman. So he can use his excellent techy skills (and Wayne's resources in secret) to come up with a diffuser after a while the army would have taken over which would take 2-3 days max. I mean it can be well coordinated and executed since they have **23 days** to do it.

Comment: Sorry for being so specific but I think the scene was **unnecessary** (to me) and there may be ways of saving the city without Batman. Imagine if this would be done, how would Bruce felt reaching Gotham after sickening work effort :). Btw I loved the trilogy.

Comment: @Najam: You're writing a different plot. That's not constructive as to the question. This isn't a post about how they could've improved the plot. You also make far too many assumptions. How would Fox have access to Wayne's resources, if the only people with access to the resources (Alfred and Bruce) are out of the picture? Bane also knew Batman's identity, thus making it unsafe to snoop around the Wayne mansion. How can you be sure that Fox could even craft the fix if he had the resources? (He couldn't fix the autopilot, remember? Bruce was the only one who could figure out how to fix it).

Comment: I think the scenes were unnecessary and I couldn't find a compelling answer. My alternatives are just there to prove that the whole Special forces thing shouldn't have been in the film since it eventually has to highlight Batman's contributions only. For the record, the whole trilogy was an assumption :) Thanks for discussing.